# ORDER BY CASE does not working?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

Hi I have SQL statement in DB2 which is working.

```
select  distinct 'IN' as STATUS,
    (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

UNION ALL

select  distinct 'OUT',
   (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

UNION ALL

select  distinct 'FINISHED',
   (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

order by status
```

But if I change the last line to

```
order by 
 case STATUS
 when 'IN' then 1
 when 'OUT' then 2
 when 'FINISHED' then 3
end
```

My query does not work.
Can someone tell me how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the error? Remember ORDER BY 1 means order by the first column, and you only have 2 columns....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping the UNION into a derived table and order on that:

```
select *
from ( 
   .... here goes your statement ...
) t
order by 
   case STATUS
      when 'IN' then 1
      when 'OUT' then 2
      when 'FINISHED' then 3
   end
```

Comment: one small question- do you know maybe can I change IN_PROGRESS to IN PROGRESS? beacuse I also has IN_PROGRESS in my query

Comment: @dejan: is "in_progress" a column or a column value?

Answer (score 1):

you could always add the sort # to the status:

```
select  distinct '1-IN' as STATUS,
    (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

UNION ALL

select  distinct '2-OUT',
   (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

UNION ALL

select  distinct '3-FINISHED',
   (select count(*) from table.......)
from table

order by status
```

Comment: this is not the solution because it will then be showed as 1-IN etc. in the table which is certainly not something that I want

Answer (score 0):

hello try this should work if i remember correctly

```
    order by 
     case 
      when STATUS='IN' then 1
      when STATUS='OUT' then 2
      when STATUS='FINISHED' then 3
     end
```

you could also name this when finishing
end as field_name

Comment: for completeness you can also add an else into the case-when, of course

Comment: that's identical to the `CASE` in the question